# Connection reset by peer: socket write error - using Jsoup

Tags: java, sockets, web-crawler, jsoup, httpclient

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:138)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1383)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1291)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:435)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:859)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:366)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:353)
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:355)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:457)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:165)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:109)
    ... 13 more
```

I met this error when I tried to get the document from a certain URL using Jsoup and I've tried to change the headers but it didn't make sense. This exception occurs randomly so I set retries as a temporary solution. Wonder if there's any other solution, Thanks :)

my method:

```
    public Document getDocumentFromTargetURL() throws Exception{
        String currentUserAgent = getRandomUserAgent();
        String currentSecChUa = getRandomSecChUa();
        headers.put("sec-ch-ua",currentSecChUa);                                                                        
        headers.put("referer",referer);
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(targetURL).headers(headers).userAgent(currentUserAgent).timeout(60000).get();
        Tool.printWhenNotNull(document);
        return document;
    }
```

Comment: The reset is happening during SSL-now-TLS handshake before any headers are sent, so they can't possibly help (or hurt). It could be the server is just flaky, or overloaded, or is not one server but a pool or some distributor/balancer with (at least) one bad member. Reset can also be injected by many kinds of network middlebox like IPS DLP WAF. If you can identify the server(s) (i.e. URL domain) it might be possible to give a specific answer; in some cases also identifying how you are connected to the Internet matters.

Comment: The IP is 2606:4700:3036::ac43:cfe3, a Cloud Flare's anycast IP. Does it mean I can just retry to avoid this problem?

Comment: Cloudflare's business is having lots of capacity, so I doubt they will be overloaded unless under serious attack -- and if that happens there's nothing you can do about it. It _could_ be some mistake or flaw in their setup, but I don't see how you could detect that much less prove it. Otherwise we can only guess what or where the actual cause is, so there's no way to predict with any confidence whether and when retrying will work -- but it might, and it's cheap, so you might as well try; at worst you still have the same problem you already had. Good luck.